# Why stores 255 in a char variable give its value -1 in C?

Tags: c, char, signed

I am reading a C book,  and there is a text the author mentioned:

"`if ch (a char variable) is a signed type, then storing 255 in the ch variable gives it the value -1`".

Can anyone elaborate on that?

Comment: and you never thought to just look up what the representation for a signed character was?

Comment: @tbert: you did not read my comment for the highest vote answer. Iam starting to find out stuff in c, and my question deserves a vote down?

Comment: given your continued confusion after having the answer explicitly provided? probably.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming 8-bit `char`s, that is actually implementation-defined behaviour. The value 255 cannot be represented as a signed 8-bit integer.

However, most implementations simply store the bit-pattern, which for 255 is `0xFF`. With a two's-complement interpretation, as a signed 8-bit integer, that is the bit-pattern of `-1`. On a rarer ones'-complement architecture, that would be the bit pattern of negative zero or a trap representation, with sign-and-magnitude, it would be `-127`.

If either of the two assumptions (signedness and 8-bit `char`s) doesn't hold, the value will be¹ 255, since 255 is representable as an unsigned 8-bit integer or as a signed (or unsigned) integer with more than 8 bits.

¹ The standard guarantees that `CHAR_BIT` is at least 8, it may be greater.

Comment: Note that it's also possible for `char` to be unsigned or to have more than 8 bits, in which case it would, in fact, be `255`

Comment: Yes. Signedness was assumed in the text the OP quoted, and I specifically mentioned the extra assumption of 8-bit `char`s. I should, however, mention the other possibilities explicitly in the answer. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I'm still lost. I understood that 255 cannot be represented in signed char because there is one bit being reserved for the sign. In that case, why the compiler just gives us undefined behavior like many others? And why the two's complement involves here? (I know how two's complement works already)

Answer (score 2):

That's how two's complement works. Read all about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: I know how two's complement works. But I dont see any relationships here. Can you explain further, please?

Answer (score 2):

Try it in decimal. Suppose we can only have 3 digits. So our unsigned range is 0 - 999.

Let's see if 999 can actually behave as -1 (signed):

```
42 + 999 = 1041
```

Because we can only have 3 digits, we drop the highest order digit (the carry):

```
041 = 42 - 1
```

This is a general rule that applies to any number base.

Comment: you meant 042 = 41 - 1 or 041 = 42 - 1

Comment: No, everything above is meant as it is.

Answer (score 2):

That is not guaranteed behavior. To quote ANSI/ISO/IEC 9899:1999 §6.3.1.3 (converting between signed and unsigned integers) clause 3:

> ```
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it;
> either the result is implementation-deﬁned or an implementation-deﬁned signal
> is raised.
> ```

I'll leave the bitwise/2's complement explanations to the other answers, but standards-compliant `signed char`s aren't even guaranteed to be too small to hold 255; they might work just fine (giving the value 255.)

Answer (score 0):

You have classical explanation in others messages. I give you a rule:

> In a signed type with size n, presence of MSB set as 1, must interpreted as -2^(n-1).

For this concrete question, assuming size of char is 8 bits length (1 bytes), 255 to binary is equal to:

```
1*2^(7) +  
1*2^(6) + 
1*2^(5) + 
1*2^(4) + 
1*2^(3) + 
1*2^(2) + 
1*2^(1) + 
1*2^(0) = 255

255 equivalent to 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1.
```

For unsigned char, you get 255, but if you are dealing with char (same as signed char), MSB represents a negative magnitude:

```
-1*2^(7) +  
1*2^(6) + 
1*2^(5) + 
1*2^(4) + 
1*2^(3) + 
1*2^(2) + 
1*2^(1) + 
1*2^(0) = -1
```